# Enabling the QT/PyQt QFileDialog "select all" keyboard shortcut on OSX?

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt

I'm developing cross platform apps using PyQt (ver 4.11.4) that use QFileDialog open file dialogs. The file dialogs are all enabled to select multiple files. On Windows, the standard CTRL-A keyboard shortcut selects all files, but on OSX the standard CMD-A keyboard shortcut does nothing.

On OSX, I can use the cursor with the SHIFT or CMD keys to select multiple files, but does anyone know how I can enable the 'select all' keyboard shortcut?

**Edit**

Following the reply below, I can now get a non-native file dialog to work. This is better than nothing, but ideally, especially on OS X, a native dialog would be much better. Is there any way to get the same effect with the native dialog?

Here is the complete code that works for non-native dialogs (basically the same as the reply below):

```
    fileDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    fileDialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
    fileDialog.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
    fileDialog.exec_()
    filenames = fileDialog.selectedFiles()
    return(filenames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.fileDlg=QtGui.QFileDialog()
self.fileDlg.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AnyFile)
self.fileDlg.setOptions(QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

You can try this maybe, I didn't test on OSX, but reading from bug reports this should be a solution.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but there was no change. The CMD-A key shortcut still doesn't work. I also tried CTRL-A, but that doesn't work either. Can you test your suggestion at your end to see if it really works?

Comment: I tried again, and now it works, but only with the non-native dialog. Is there any way to use a native dialog with the same effect?

Comment: Its a know bug with Qt and Osx , you can find lots in google. Qt5 + fixed and I am not sure any other work around.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as the correct answer, because for the time being, this is probably the only thing that works.